# codeigniter multi database connection problem

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

```html
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| DATABASE CONNECTIVITY SETTINGS
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file will contain the settings needed to access your database.
|
| For complete instructions please consult the 'Database Connection'
| page of the User Guide.
|
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| EXPLANATION OF VARIABLES
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|
|   ['dsn']      The full DSN string describe a connection to the database.
|   ['hostname'] The hostname of your database server.
|   ['username'] The username used to connect to the database
|   ['password'] The password used to connect to the database
|   ['database'] The name of the database you want to connect to
|   ['dbdriver'] The database driver. e.g.: mysqli.
|           Currently supported:
|                cubrid, ibase, mssql, mysql, mysqli, oci8,
|                odbc, pdo, postgre, sqlite, sqlite3, sqlsrv
|   ['dbprefix'] You can add an optional prefix, which will be added
|                to the table name when using the  Query Builder class
|   ['pconnect'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether to use a persistent connection
|   ['db_debug'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether database errors should be displayed.
|   ['cache_on'] TRUE/FALSE - Enables/disables query caching
|   ['cachedir'] The path to the folder where cache files should be stored
|   ['char_set'] The character set used in communicating with the database
|   ['dbcollat'] The character collation used in communicating with the database
|                NOTE: For MySQL and MySQLi databases, this setting is only used
|                as a backup if your server is running PHP < 5.2.3 or MySQL < 5.0.7
|                (and in table creation queries made with DB Forge).
|                There is an incompatibility in PHP with mysql_real_escape_string() which
|                can make your site vulnerable to SQL injection if you are using a
|                multi-byte character set and are running versions lower than these.
|                Sites using Latin-1 or UTF-8 database character set and collation are unaffected.
|   ['swap_pre'] A default table prefix that should be swapped with the dbprefix
|   ['encrypt']  Whether or not to use an encrypted connection.
|   ['compress'] Whether or not to use client compression (MySQL only)
|   ['stricton'] TRUE/FALSE - forces 'Strict Mode' connections
|                           - good for ensuring strict SQL while developing
|   ['failover'] array - A array with 0 or more data for connections if the main should fail.
|   ['save_queries'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether to "save" all executed queries.
|               NOTE: Disabling this will also effectively disable both
|               $this->db->last_query() and profiling of DB queries.
|               When you run a query, with this setting set to TRUE (default),
|               CodeIgniter will store the SQL statement for debugging purposes.
|               However, this may cause high memory usage, especially if you run
|               a lot of SQL queries ... disable this to avoid that problem.
|
| The $active_group variable lets you choose which connection group to
| make active.  By default there is only one group (the 'default' group).
|
| The $query_builder variables lets you determine whether or not to load
| the query builder class.
*/

$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'bpiu',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => 'acms_',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => 'application/cache',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
$db['otherdb'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'test3',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => 'acms_',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => 'application/cache',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I am working on a project and trying to implement multiple databases in codeigniter but getting error. I have tried multiple solutions but the problem is still there. I am using codeigniter version 3.1.11

```
    $active_group = 'default';
    $query_builder = TRUE;
    
    $db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'bpiu',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => 'acms_',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => 'application/cache',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
    
    
    $db['otherdb'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'test3',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => 'acms_',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => 'application/cache',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
```

In this line I am getting error You have specified an invalid database connection group.

```
    $this->load->database('otherdb', TRUE);
```

This is the complete database.php file and i am getting error, in other file i am using         `$otherdb=$this->load->database('otherdb', TRUE);`
this code in constructor, but it shows error
"You have specified an invalid database connection group."

Comment: Can you post the entire database.php file, also the file you're using to connect and the actual error?

Comment: i have attached the database file, in Model file in am trying to load database in constructor, but it shows error "You have specified an invalid database connection group."

Comment: I also have mentioned line of code used in constructor

Comment: problem is fixed, there was multiple database.php files that caused problem.

Comment: So you had a database.php file for each environment?

Answer (score 0):

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
```

This is the part which sets the group name. Notice on the 'default' db the first parameter of the array is ['default']. You just need to add:

```
$active_group = 'otherdb';
$active_record = TRUE;
```

Comment: that sets your default database to be used. OP wants to load other database connection that is not the default one.

Comment: i have updated the code but still same problem exists